# Using the MVC pattern, should my domain objects know about my persistence entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dry, single-responsibility-principle

I often find myself writing implementation details of the presistence layer in my domain objects. In my upcoming example, it seems useful to be able to pass a `PersonRecord` into the constructor in order to map the properties.

**Note:** The `PersonRecord` is an Entity Framework entity in this example.

```
public class Person 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public Person(Data.persistence.PersonRecord entity)
    {
        Id = entity.Id
        Name = entity.Name
        Email = entity.Email
    }
}
```

I also find it useful to map the properties back to the entity when saving the data.

```
public void UpdateEntity(Data.persistence.PersonRecord entity)
{
    entity.Id = Id
    entity.Name = Name
    entity.Email = Email
}
```

I then have a repository for this entity which performs the saving.

The concerns I have about this approach is that my domain objects are coupled with Entity Framework making it arduous to replace along with other `SRP` violation issues.

Are my concerns warranted?

I can overcome the constructor issue by swapping the dependency around, taking each property as a parameter and passing in those values inside the repository.

I can do the same for updating the entity, I wouldn't need any extra logic in the domain model but rather let the repository be responsible for mapping the properties.

By doing these things however I also need to do the following:

1. Every retrieval method in the repository will need to map the value of each property across on the domain object's constructor. This violates the `DRY` principle unless that logic is abstracted into a factory function etc.
2. The update method in the repository will also be required to map each property, this seems okay as there will likely only be one update method.

Am I missing a trick?

if not, which is the best approach?

Comment: Maybe you should use AutoMapper

Comment: AutoMapper looks great for large projects with lots of models but how about for projects where it's not worth adding a dependency to an external library. There must be a relatively painless way of doing this?

Comment: Automapper should be built into MVC. It is continually updated, it's creator (Jimmy Bogard) is an MVC guru. It's a very painless nuget package install. I particularly like the `Project().To<myViewModel>()` syntax.

Comment: Entity Framework is an Object Relational Mapper.  Your PersonRecord class is your domain entity.  EF makes makes mapping this to databse structures using either  attributes or mapping directly with EntityTypeConfiguration.  You shouldn't need another layer in the middle.  You should be using view models but those should be reflect your view.  Putting it together requires mapping from your domain model to the screen.  This could be done with AutoMapper, by hand, projecting directly into your view models, but in no case should your classes be dependent across "tiers."

Comment: @Fran I think you've touched on something I've misunderstood due to working in a database first environment. Since the entity classes are generated (meaning any changes I make without using partials will disappear after refreshing the EDMX) I've always shied away from using entities as anything more than DTOs. Instead I can create my domain objects and then use EF to do the mapping.